# Rails 3 - Distinct and Random

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to choose 5 distinct brands from among the cars that belong to my users. My current attempt is below (no approach to selecting at random).

```
@range = @user.cars.select('DISTINCT brand_id').limit(5)
```

How might I select these five random distinct brands? Thank you very much.

Comment: Which DB engine are you using? (MySQL, SQLite etc?)

Comment: MySQL - although, the select('DISTINCT brand_id') isn't working even alone.

Comment: cars is an associated table: User has_many :cars

Answer (score 0):

Although not very elegant, I might select all your distinct brands and then pick 5 at random. In this case, I expect your list of brands is not very large so the initial query shouldn't be too expensive.

```
brands = @user.cars.select('DISTINCT brand_id')
selection = 5.times.map{ Random.new.rand(0..brands.size) } # Random requires Ruby 1.9.2+
@range = []
selection.each { |rec| @range << brands[rec] }
```

This is untested code so apologies if I've mislead.

Comment: It seems to have an issue doing DISTINCT on @user.cars. It seems to work directly on a model but not on related records.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you need a table name qualifier, e.g. 'DISTINCT \`cars\`.brand_id'

Answer (score 0):

The code given in the question chooses five car brands that belong to one particular user.  That's a pretty lucky user.

If we assume that you're trying to choose five brands at random from all the cars owned by at least one of your users, I think you want something like this:

```
Car.select("DISTINCT cars.brand_id").order("RANDOM()").joins(:user).limit(5)
```

That should work so long as Car has a belong_to relationship to User.

If you really want to limit the scope to just a single user's cars, then you want something like this:

```
@user.cars.select("DISTINCT cars.brand_id").order("RANDOM()").limit(5)
```

For what it's worth, in mysql you need "order(RAND())" rather than "order(RANDOM())".

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you picking distinct records

```
@range = @user.cars.select('brand_id').uniq.limit(5)
```